# Настройка .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Есть:

```
сайт.ru/author/ник
```

Как сделать ридерект на главную если человек обращается к странице любого из авторов?

Comment: @rodion, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

В папку "author" вкинь файл .htaccess с таким содержанием:

```
deny from all
ErrorDocument 403 /
```

А работает это так: мы блокируем доступ ко всей директории, следовательно, нам даёт код 403, и перенаправление на главную.